# Installing new software in Spring

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

I'm learning how to use Spring Tools Suite v4 and I ran into this problem.  I'm attempting to install new software via Help->Install new software...  I want the following two packages, Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools 3.7.0.v201602161345 and Eclipse Web Developer Tools    3.7.1.v201602111638.

After selecting the packages and clicking "Next", I can see that at the bottom of the window it says "Cannot not perform operation.  Computing alternate solutions, may take a while. 1 of 15".

The error message at the end is:

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=DefaultProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.sun.xml.bind,2.2.0.v201505121915
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,javax.xml.soap,1.3.0.v201105210645

I'd like to know whether you've had this happen and whether there is a solution to this at all.

Comment: If you take note of the datestamps embedded in those version numbers, they're from 2016. Did you have to add a URL to find those features? You should be using https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest for the current release.

Comment: I used http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars.

Comment: I tried "latest" link, but got the same kind of error messasge:  An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=DefaultProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jetty.osgi-servlet-api,3.1.0.M3

Comment: This time I got:  "An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=DefaultProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.sun.xml.bind,2.2.0.v201505121915
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,javax.xml.soap,1.3.0.v201105210645"

Comment: Which STS4 and Eclipse releases are you starting from?

Comment: What do mean exactly with "starting"?

Comment: Note that this is not _Spring_; it is _Spring Tool Suite_, which is a version of Eclipse bundled with extras to make it easier to write software _using_ Spring.

Comment: Which versions are you using? Mars hasn't been a supported release for years.

Comment: I'm using the latest versions.

Comment: Sorry about the mistake, chrylis.

Comment: I found the answer by Binging the issue I was having.  It turns out that de-selecting "Contact all update sites during install to find required software" improves the download performance.  After that, the installation process finished in no time.